# Node Mssql module error: RequestError: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database

I´m using mssql module on node js, when I try to use this query:

```
 const search = await mssql.query`SELECT
    numpis,
    datadm,
    r006esc.nomesc
  FROM
    r034fun
    join r006esc on (r006esc.codesc = r034fun.codesc)
  WHERE
    CONCAT(numcad, '-', tipcol, '-', numemp) = (
      SELECT
        TOP 1 CONCAT(numcad, '-', tipcol, '-', numemp)
      FROM
        r034fun as tbl2
      WHERE
        tbl2.numpis = r034fun.numpis
      ORDER BY
        datadm DESC
    )
    AND NUMPIS IN(${pisString});`
```

It returns the error:

> RequestError: Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

But when I run in an SQL editor, like beekeper, it works perfectly.

The pisString used on query:

```
let pisString = ``
    await object.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (index !== object.length - 1) pisString += `${element.numpis},`
      else pisString += `${element.numpis}`
    })
```

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: Aren't you missing parenthesis in mssql.query(`...`)?

Comment: No, strangely that`s the syntax for queries on this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was, to find many values in the IN statement I had to pass an array of values, like `[123, 456, 789]` and not a string `123, 456, 789` like I was doing. The mssql module was reading the string as a single value and not many values.